# C++11 Muted Thread Pool

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I just finished writing a Thread Pool in C++11 and wanted to get some feedback since I'm not particularly experienced in multithreaded programming, I used to have a thread pool written in Boost::Asio mostly using their work dispatcher and io_service. This thread pool implementation seems to block less and has a slightly more reliable framerate in my game when used for particle effects.

Any feedback on performance improvements would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

https://github.com/M2tM/MutedThreadPool

```
#ifndef _MV_THREADPOOL_H_
#define _MV_THREADPOOL_H_

#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

namespace MV {
    class ThreadPool {
        class Worker;
    public:
        class Job {
            friend Worker;
        public:
            Job(const std::function<void()> &a_action) :
                action(a_action) {
            }
            Job(const std::function<void()> &a_action, const std::function<void()> &a_onFinish) :
                action(a_action),
                onFinish(a_onFinish) {
            }
            Job(const std::function<void()> &a_action, const std::function<void()> &a_onFinish, const std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<size_t>> &a_groupCounter, const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> &a_onGroupFinish) :
                action(a_action),
                onFinish(a_onFinish),
                groupCounter(a_groupCounter),
                onGroupFinish(a_onGroupFinish) {
            }
            Job(const std::function<void()> &a_action, const std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<size_t>> &a_groupCounter, const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> &a_onGroupFinish) :
                action(a_action),
                groupCounter(a_groupCounter),
                onGroupFinish(a_onGroupFinish) {
            }
            Job(Job&& a_rhs) = default;
            Job(const Job& a_rhs) = default;

            void group(const std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<size_t>> &a_groupCounter, const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> &a_onGroupFinish) {
                groupCounter = a_groupCounter;
                onGroupFinish = a_onGroupFinish;
            }

            void operator()() noexcept {
                try { action(); } catch (std::exception &e) { parent->exception(e); }
                bool groupFinished = groupCounter && --(*groupCounter) == 0 && onGroupFinish && *onGroupFinish;
                if (onFinish && !groupFinished) {
                    parent->task(onFinish);
                }
                else if (onFinish && groupFinished) {
                    parent->task([=] {
                        try { onFinish(); } catch (std::exception &e) { parent->exception(e); }
                        try { (*onGroupFinish)(); } catch (std::exception &e) { parent->exception(e); }
                    });
                }
                else if (groupFinished) {
                    parent->task((*onGroupFinish));
                }
            }
        private:
            ThreadPool* parent;

            std::function<void()> action;
            std::function<void()> onFinish;
            std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<size_t>> groupCounter;
            std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> onGroupFinish;
        };
        friend Job;
    private:
        class Worker {
        public:
            Worker(ThreadPool* a_parent) :
                parent(a_parent) {
                thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([=]() { work(); });
            }
            ~Worker() { if (thread && thread->joinable()) { thread->join(); } }

            void cleanup() {
                while (!finished) {}
            }
        private:
            void work() {
                while (!parent->stopped) {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(parent->lock);
                    parent->notify.wait(guard, [=] {return parent->jobs.size() > 0 || parent->stopped; });
                    if (parent->stopped) { break; }

                    auto job = std::move(parent->jobs.front());
                    parent->jobs.pop_front();
                    guard.unlock();

                    job.parent = parent;
                    job();
                }
                finished = true;
            }
            ThreadPool* parent;
            bool finished = false;
            std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread;
        };
        friend Worker;

    public:
        ThreadPool() :
            ThreadPool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency() > 1 ? std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1 : 1) {
        }

        ThreadPool(size_t a_threads) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < a_threads; ++i) {
                workers.push_back(std::make_unique<Worker>(this));
            }
        }

        ~ThreadPool() {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
                jobs.clear();
                stopped = true;
            }
            notify.notify_all();
            for (auto&& worker : workers) {
                worker->cleanup();
            }
        }

        void task(const Job &a_newWork) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
                jobs.emplace_back(std::move(a_newWork));
            }
            notify.notify_one();
        }
        void task(const std::function<void()> &a_task) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
                jobs.emplace_back(a_task);
            }
            notify.notify_one();
        }
        void task(const std::function<void()> &a_task, const std::function<void()> &a_onComplete) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
                jobs.emplace_back(a_task, a_onComplete);
            }
            notify.notify_one();
        }

        void tasks(const std::vector<Job> &a_tasks, const std::function<void()> &a_onGroupComplete) {
            std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<size_t>> counter = std::make_shared<std::atomic<size_t>>(a_tasks.size());
            std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> sharedGroupComplete = std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(std::move(a_onGroupComplete));
            for (auto&& job : a_tasks)
            {
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
                    jobs.emplace_back(std::move(job));
                    jobs.back().group(counter, sharedGroupComplete);
                }
                notify.notify_one();
            }
        }

        void schedule(const std::function<void()> &a_method) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(scheduleLock);
            scheduled.push_back(a_method);
        }

        void run() {
            for (auto i = scheduled.begin(); i != scheduled.end();) {
                try {
                    (*i)();
                } catch (std::exception &e) {
                    exception(e);
                }

                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(scheduleLock);
                scheduled.erase(i++);
            }
        }

        void exceptionHandler(std::function<void(std::exception &e)> a_onException) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(exceptionLock);
            onException = a_onException;
        }

        size_t threads() const {
            return workers.size();
        }
    private:
        void exception(std::exception &e) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(exceptionLock);
            if (onException) {
                onException(e);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Uncaught Exception in Thread Pool: " << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }

        std::condition_variable notify;
        bool stopped = false;
        std::mutex lock;
        std::mutex scheduleLock;
        std::mutex exceptionLock;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> workers;
        std::deque<Job> jobs;
        std::list<std::function<void()>> scheduled;
        std::deque<std::string> exceptionMessages;
        std::function<void(std::exception &e)> onException;
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: Any specific reason (other than lifetime management) why `groupCounter` has to be `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<size_t>>` instead of `std::atomic<size_t>&`? Same question for `onGroupFinish`.

Comment: Much too large and complicated. Thread pools have been reviewed several times before. Check out some of the existing thread pools and see if you can steal from them to simplify your implementation. **PS** modern C++ should not need such low level primitives as they are the same functionality is provided by the standard. You should be using higher level abstractions like `std::promise` `std::future` and `std::async`

Comment: @hoffmale Lifetime management is the reason they are std::shared_ptr, they are not references because they are not necessary unless they are part of a group, and being part of a group is optional. So not every task has a groupCounter or onGroupFinish. They are actually shared pointers because they are shared state between the group.

Comment: @LokiAstari Yeah I had considered making use of the std::future interface, but unfortunately the lack of a std::when_all and std::future::then makes the standard a little immature for my most common use case which is chaining together continuations. Maybe in a few years when std::future is more composable I will re-visit this.

std::async is cool, but is an awkward place for use in general code because I can't control how many threads I get, and that matters on iOS (really don't want too many), and I don't think it's much simpler than worker dispatching with that constraint. I'm open to it.

Comment: @LokiAstari But I would honestly need you to point me at an example of std::async in a thread pool, I haven't seen any yet. It feels like it's a kind of abstraction meant for use in a higher level than a thread pool, but it is too low level to be useful generally without guarantees about its own thread creation policies.  IE: If I use std::async directly in my particle emitters, and each emitter doesn't know about others (they are components in a scene graph) each emitter may create x threads and that would be .5 MB of ram per job basically. With a thread pool I have more explicit control.

Comment: @LokiAstari I know Microsoft's implementation of std::async uses thread pools, but not every implementation does, and my code runs on multiple platforms so I want stronger guarantees and more consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## unused variable

As far as I can tell, `ThreadPool::exceptionMessages` is currently not used.

## `const shared_ptr<T>&`

They are used quite a lot (especially on the `Job` constructors). You might want to consider exchanging them for simple `std::shared_ptr<T>` instead - you'll make a copy either way, and this way the caller knows you are taking a copy (a `const shared_ptr<T>&` says "might take", a `shared_ptr<T>` enforces it) and the compiler might be able to optimize better.

## trying to move a const object

In `ThreadPool::tasks` there is the following statement: `jobs.emplace_back(std::move(job))`. This will always make a copy! Why? Because `job` is a value contained in `a_tasks`, which is `const` - so it can't be modified. Note that in case you switched `a_task` to a non-`const` vector, it will contain invalid values afterwards (as they will have been moved from).

## batch performance

This again concerns `ThreadPool::tasks`: When enqueueing a batch of N jobs, 2*N+2 `shared_ptr` objects will be constructed (and once the jobs are finished, they'll have to be destructed again). Since those operations can be costly and can be avoided (with some architectural changes), there might be some performance gains (mostly in case of smaller jobs).

## race condition

There is a possible (and very likely, unless `scheduled` is nearly empty) race condition in `ThreadPool::run`: If `run` were to be called concurrently, there might be cases where the object currently pointed to by `i` will be erased by another thread (as it is already finished processing the function pointed to by `i`).

## data structures

This might be highly situational (call it "premature optimization" if you will), but one could exchange `ThreadPool::scheduled` for a `vector`. This might boost performance a bit in case you schedule lots of functions, as you are chasing less pointers around (= less cache misses).

Nearly the same could be said for `ThreadPool::jobs` (exchange it for a circular buffer implementation), especially if you have a good guess on how many jobs you might have queued up at the same time (Same reason: less pointers to chase = less cache misses).

However, these gains might be very small compared to your usual usage, so always measure!

## on another note

With regards to performance, have you tried going lock-free? I know, it makes reasoning about stuff harder, but it might give you another edge of performance if really needed (especially on platforms where locking requires kernel calls).

Comment: SUPER good feedback, thank you for your time. I'll reply to a few points, but I just want to say I'm definitely taking some of these things to heart and will be improving the implementation and posting a second version in my question.

I think of "run" as being a main thread callback invocation point. So I wasn't so concerned with "run" itself being called on multiple threads, it was not intended to.  It is meant to run in a game loop basically and to allow other threads to make calls on the main thread.

Comment: Talking more about "run" and the data structure I use for those callbacks. I make use of std::list to avoid invalidating iterators during iteration to allow for more conservative locking (rather than locking for the whole traversal of scheduled I only lock on a per callback basis. This avoids holding the mutex for too long and causing extra contention between threads.

Comment: Unused variable: Thank you for pointing it out! I'll remove it. Originally I was playing with a couple different ideas for handling exceptions, and I wrote that and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Trying to move a const object: yeah, I realize the std::move results in a straight copy instead of actually moving. I introduced the copy constructor in response to that, but did not change the move calls. I should have either found a way to properly move jobs into the queue or gotten rid of the misleading std::move.

Comment: I'll change my const std::shared_ptr<T>& to just be std::shared_ptr<T> as per your advice, it makes it clearer.

Comment: I have considered lock-free, but also am considering mobile battery life. I believe relinquishing control and avoiding busy spinlocks will help in that regard. It may be worth investigating and attempting a hybrid approach somehow though with a custom spin_mutex sort of thing. Do you have any reading suggestions or library examples of a hybrid?

Comment: if you have a hour (or two), you might find this interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs (a great talk from Herb Sutter about lock-free programming and its difficulties)

Comment: Also, are jobs calling `ThreadPool::schedule`? In that case, you need to be careful, otherwise you might turn `ThreadPool::run` into an infinite loop (jobs schedule a function, main thread runs said function, which adds jobs, which schedule a function, which...)

Comment: Yes, jobs call ThreadPool::schedule and it's technically possible to create an infinite loop if a thread is scheduling faster than the main thread can increment continuously as the list is infinitely added.

However, in practice this would probably cause other problems if a thread is scheduling incredibly fast in terms of performance even if we don't allow it to continue iterating till the end.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to cache the end iterator at the start before entering the loop. I'll write it like:

auto end = schedule.end(); for(auto i = schedule.begin();i != end;){...} to address this defect.

Comment: That's one way to address the issue (note I've been careful not to give any solutions, as they have different advantages and disadvantages in different use cases, and I don't know yours well enough, especially considering performance). If it works for you, great! If it doesn't (or doesn't work in the general case), adjust (and measure)!